# How to group elements NativeScript UI?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How to group elements in block?

```
<Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;"></Label>
<Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name"></Label>
<Label class="footnote" text="username@mail.com"></Label>
```

I need to do something like:

```
<div class="inline">
    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;"></Label>
    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name"></Label>
    <Label class="footnote" text="username@mail.com"></Label>
</div>
<div class="inline">
    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;"></Label>
    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name"></Label>
    <Label class="footnote" text="username@mail.com"></Label>
</div>
<div class="inline">
    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;"></Label>
    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name"></Label>
    <Label class="footnote" text="username@mail.com"></Label>
</div>
```

Where `<div class="inline">` is inline block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is alternative of DIV in NativeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906330/what-is-alternative-of-div-in-nativescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `div` with `StackLayout` and set the `orientation` as `horizontal`.

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;"></Label>
        <Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name"></Label>
        <Label class="footnote" text="username@mail.com"></Label>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;"></Label>
        <Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name 1"></Label>
        <Label class="footnote" text="username@mail.com"></Label>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;"></Label>
        <Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name"></Label>
        <Label class="footnote" text="username2@mail.com"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

You can give it a try in playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=iEyJ2C). 
You mentioned in your question that you want to use `inline-block` (Compared to display: inline, the major difference is that display: inline-block allows to set a width and height on the element.), then you should use `GridLayout`, it allows you to choose row and columns for you elements. The width of a column and the height of a row can be specified as an absolute amount of pixels, as a percentage of the available space or automatically:

**Absolute**: Fixed size of pixels.

**Star** (*): Takes as much space as available (after filling all auto and fixed sized columns), proportionally divided over all star-sized columns. So 3/7 means the same as 30/70.

**Auto**: Takes as much space as needed by the contained child element(s).

```
<GridLayout columns="*, *, *" rows="*, *, *" width="400" height="400"
    backgroundColor="lightgray">
    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;" row="0"
        col="0"></Label>
    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name" row="0"
        col="1"></Label>
    <Label class="footnote" text="username@mail.com" row="0" col="2"></Label>

    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;" row="1"
        col="0"></Label>
    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name" row="1"
        col="1"></Label>
    <Label class="footnote" text="username@mail.com" row="1" col="2"></Label>

    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;" row="2"
        col="0"></Label>
    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name" row="2"
        col="1"></Label>
    <Label class="footnote" text="username@mail.com" row="2" col="2"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```