# What is alternative of DIV in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

What is alternative of DIV in NativeScript?

How to use block inline with content inside?

Comment: In mobile development there's no DIV, only views

Comment: Probably a layout, like `StackLayout`

Comment: How is name this element in NativeScript? I need to group some element in block and show these blocks inline

Comment: How to create three block using `StackLayout` with the same content? `<Label class="sidedrawer-header-image fa" text="&#xf2bd;"></Label>
                    <Label class="sidedrawer-header-brand" text="User Name"></Label>
                    <Label class="footnote" text="username@mail.com"></Label>`?

Comment: Take a look at [NS Layout guide](https://www.nslayouts.com/), it is really useful.

Comment: Okay, but how to group content by inline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within Browser the behaviour `div` is determined by `display` CSS attribute.

For example, by default it's `block` and vertical which is similar to `StackLayout` with `orientation` set to `vertical`. When you make it `inline`, that's more like a horizontal layout, so again could be `StackLayout` with `orientation` set to `horizontal`.

There is again `flex`, we also have an equivalent in NativeScript, the   `FlexboxLayout`. If you set `position` to `absolute` on `div`, it can be compared to `AbsoluteLayout` in NativeScript.

There is also `GridLayout`, `WrapLayout`, and `DockLayout` in NativeScript that serves various purposes.

So the alternative for `div` here totally depends on what kind of UI / layout you are looking for / how exactly you have styled the `div` on web.

If you are beginner, https://www.nslayouts.com/ is a good start to know all about NativeScript layouts.

Comment: So, replace each block `div` on `StackLayout`?

Comment: You could, but you also want to be aware of how many layouts and views you're adding to your UI. Each view has to measure, draw and render which takes time. The more condensed your layout the better. So in some scenarios a GridLayout with rows/columns is better than putting 10 stack layouts to achieve the same UI layout.

Comment: Could you share an example, when I have some blocks inline with some labels inside, please